# Why are my buttons transparent when I run on my device?

Tags: android, css, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I've colored my buttons in my App. When I'm running on a local server on my PC the colors work fine, but when I deploy to my Device(Android), all buttons are transparent.

in my variables.scss it looks like this:

```
ion-button{
    --background: #a37001e8;
    --background-activated: #e9c067e8;
    color: white;
  }
```

Comment: are you using cordova or capacitor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ion-button{
    --background: rgba(163, 112, 1, 1);
    --background-activated: rgba(233, 192, 103, 1)
    color: white;
  }
```

There is not yet full browser support for alpha use of a hex color. Use the rgba() function only accepts a value in R, G, B, A (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) format. https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#the-alpha-problem